# Arabic Characters in URL returns 404 Error

Tags: server, characters, vps

I have Arabic Characters in my URLs of my site.
After setup my new VPS with LAMP and importing my local site into it, my Arabic URLs return 404 error and show me none-scene characters like below:

```
The requested URL /Ø®Ø¯Ù…Ø§Øª-Ú¯Ø±Ø¯Ø´Ú¯Ø±ÛŒ/ was not found on this server.
```

I'm double check `mode_rewrite` is enabled and my Charset of my SQL database is `UTF-8` and tables are `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8mb_general_ci`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue as you. I was trying to access the following URL, which results in a 404 error:

> ```
> The requested URL `/abb/public/main/category/ÙƒÙ…Ø§Ù„` was not found on this server.
> ```

[http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/كمال](http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/%D9%83%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84)
or
http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/%D9%83%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84

while accessing
[http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/فتنس](http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%B3)
http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%B3
or
http://localhost/abb/public/main/category/ABCDEF
works fine.

I found the cause of issue in `.htaccess` file. It was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)$ abb/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and I changed it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)$ abb/index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```

and then it worked.