# wordpress sub-category ( lowercase letters + non-latin characters ) = 404

Tags: categories, permalinks, slug

If the sub-category's slug is a combination of lowercase letters and Korean, page 404 appears.

[image]

1 : **NGINX settings**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

2 : **Wordpress - Permerlink settings**

- Custom: /%category%/%postname%/
- Category Base:.

3 : **Wordpress - Yoast**

- Taxonomies > Category URLs ( Remove )

4 : **Tested content**

4-1 : In case of parent category ✅

- mywebsite.com/한글 = 200
- mywebsite.com/a한글 = 200
- mywebsite.com/한글B = 200

4-2 : In case of post ✅

- mywebsite.com/한글/post글 = 200 ( lowercase + non-latin )

4-3 : In case of child category ⚠️

- mywebsite.com/한글/한글  = 200
- mywebsite.com/한글/a한글 = 404 ❌
- mywebsite.com/한글/한글b = 404 ❌
- mywebsite.com/한글/C한글 = 200
- mywebsite.com/한글/한글D = 200
- mywebsite.com%2F%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80%2Fa%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80 = 200 ⭕️ ( /한글/a한글 : url encoded )
- mywebsite.com/한글/A한글 = 200 ⭕️ ( /한글/a한글 : uppercase )

5 : **Reference question**

<s>https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277401/arabic-characters-in-url-returns-404-error</s>

<s>I think it might be related to @user139986 's answer.</s>

I don't know how to handle this problem ..

Comment: Looking at @user139986's answer (linked in your question): In the `.htaccess` file, the `NC` indicates `no case`, ie, the request should be considered in a case-insensitive manner. This means that, say, `ABC` = `abc` = `AbC`. Does [this question and its answer(s)](https://serverfault.com/questions/498855/nginx-case-insensitive-rewrite) help you out?

Comment: @PatJ Thanks for explaining. I guess I misunderstood that it has something to do with user139986's answer.  The lowercase letters are the problem, so it doesn't seem to be related.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️ Temporary workaround

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59109698/15497563

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

**nginx.conf**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170826/15497563

```
http {
    # Include the perl module
    perl_modules perl/lib;

    # Define this function
    perl_set $uri_uppercase 'sub {
        my $r = shift;
        my $uri = $r->uri;
        $uri = uc($uri);
        return $uri;
    }';
}
```

**site-enabled**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369570/15497563

```
server {
    location ~ ^/(부모/자식a|부모/자식b|부모/자식c)(.*) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_uppercase;
    }
}
```

Every time you create a sub-category(lowercase letters + non-latin characters), you need to edit it...